# Color each edge in triangle (igraph)

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to color triangles in a graph using `igraph` in `R`. The graph `g` below has a bow-tie shape, and I would like to color the two triangles differently.

```
library(igraph)
edge_vector <- c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5)
g <- make_undirected_graph(edge_vector)
g
plot(g)
```

[image]

I can identify the triangles as follows, where each column makes up the three vertices in the triangle.

```
T <- matrix(triangles(g), nrow=3)
print(T)
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    3    3
## [2,]    1    4
## [3,]    2    5
```

Looping through the columns, i.e. for each triangle, I can form the three edges of the triangle as numeric pairs (e.g. 3,1 and 3,2 and 1,2), but how can I then perform a look-up on those edges in `E(g)`, for example, so that I can set the color attribute of each edge?

I realize in a larger graph, an edge may be in multiple triangles, but I'd like to know how to do it in this simple case.

Answer (score 2):

```
colors <- c("blue", "red")
for (i in seq(ncol(T))){
  E(g, c(T[1, i], T[2, i], 
         T[1, i], T[3, i], 
         T[2, i], T[3, i]))$color <- colors[i]
}
plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: How to color two triangles with the common edge?